# Vue.js: is it possible to have a SFC factory?

Tags: vue.js

I'm using single-file-components in a larger project and I'm new to Vue.JS. I'm looking for a way to dynamically create components, especially their templates on-the-fly at run-time.

My idea is to create a "component factory" also as a SFC and to parameterize it with props, e.g. one for the template, one for the data and so forth. I get how this works for already specified SFC and that I can simply exchange them with `<component v-bind:is= ...`, however the task here is different. I need to compose a template string, which potentially is composed of other component instance declarations, on-the-fly and inject it in another SFC. The code below doesn't work unfortunately.

```
<template>
  <div>
    <produced-component/>
  </div>
</template>

<style></style>

<script>

import Vue from 'vue'

export default {
  props: {
    template: { type: String, default: '<div>no template prop provided</div>' }
  },
  components: {
    'produced-component': Vue.extend(
      {
        template: '<div>my runtime template, this I want to be able to compose on-the-fly</div>'
      }
    )
  }
}
</script>
```

It says:

[image]

The following answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44648296/4432432 answers the question partially but I can't figure out how to use this concept in the context of single-file-components.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

---

**Edit 2020.03.16**:

For future reference the final result of the SFC factory achieved as per the accepted answer looks like this:

```
<template>
  <component:is="loader"/>
</template>

<script>
const compiler = require('vue-template-compiler')
import Vue from 'vue'

export default {
  props: {
    templateSpec: { type: String, default: '<div>no template provided</div>' }
  },
  computed: {
    loader () {
      let compSpec = {
        ...compiler.compileToFunctions(this.templateSpec)
      }
      return Vue.extend(compSpec)
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can surely have a Factory component with SFC; though what you are trying to do is a very rare case scenario and seems more like an anti/awkward pattern.

Whatever, you are doing currently is right. All you need to do is - use **Full build** of Vue which include the **Vue Template Compiler**, which will enable you to compile template at run-time (on the browser when app is running). But remember that for the components written in SFC, they must be compiled at build time by `vue-loader` or rollup equivalent plugin.

#### Instead of using `vue.runtime.min.js` or `vue.runtime.js`, use `vue.min.js` or `vue.js`.

Read Vue [installation docs for more details](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/installation.html#Explanation-of-Different-Builds).

Assuming you are using Webpack, by default `main` field of Vue's `package.json` file points to the runtime build. Thus you are getting this error. You must tell webpack to use full bundle. In the configuration resolve the `Vue` imports to the following file:

#### webpack.config.js

```
module.exports = {
    // ... other config

    resolve: {
        alias: {
            'vue$': 'vue/dist/vue.esm.js'
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. As for the pattern remark - I agree that it strays away from the standard way of doing things. My code was a mere suggestion, one of many things I tried. I'm just looking for the proper Vue way of actually specifying the template on-the-fly. I guess from your answer that actually using the full build is not the proper way. Is there any workaround so that I can satisfy this requirement? Maybe having a call to a (backend) instance which can actually compile the template and include it using an async call?

Comment: @el.nicko, no problem in using full Vue build. Angular does that. The problem is the pattern as you rightly mentioned. Go ahead and use full build if you need it. If you want the same functionality but do not want to use full-build, use JSX (again build-based) or use `h` notation and write render function directly as [mentioned in the docs](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/render-function.html). This does not need compiler but it is very cumbersome to write.

Comment: Harshal, I followed your advice partially and succeeded in creating a generic component factory by importing the vue-template-compiler and v-bind:is. Thank you for the help.